# RethinkDB, add derived columns on result

Tags: rethinkdb

I can seem to do this via map+merge

```
map( function(row) {
   return row.merge( { newCol: 'ABC' } );
});
```

Problem is if I want to do a lookup from a static map e.g.

var LOOKUP_MAP = {key1: {text: 'Key 1'}};

Then below doesn't work

```
map( function(row) {
   return row.merge({ newCol: LOOKUP_MAP[row('key')].text });
});
```

row('key'); seems to be lazily evaluated. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sth like this:

```
var LOOKUP_MAP = {key1: {text: 'Key 1'}};

r.db('salaries').table('salaries')
.map( function(row) {
   return row.merge({ newCol: r.expr(LOOKUP_MAP)(row('key'))('text') });
});
```

Comment: this works. I can't seem to upvote this. Marking as answer.